# HTML/CSS render divs conditionally and in specific position on the page

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

It's been a while since I worked purely with html. I have a drop down with some options, and based on selection I'd like to display some div at a specific position on the page.

Initially, all the inputs divs are hidden since the "please make a selection" is the pre-selected option in the drop down. Since the divs are rendered and hidden, they're always attached to the DOM. Ideally, I'd like to display a div with their respective drop down option right underneath the submit button once user make their selection from the drop down. If a user selects height, div_id3 is displayed, but div 1 and 2 takes up space because of the hidden css prop. Is there any way (using css and/html) to display div 3 or div 2 immediately underneath my submit button. Please ask for clarifications if I am confusing anyone.

```html
<select id="selection_id" name="selection_id" class="form-control">
    <option>Please Make A Selection</option>
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="age">Age</option>
    <option value="height">Height</option>
</select>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3"><input class="col-md-12 same_class_name" id="div_id1" type="text" placeholder="name"  style="display:none;" required></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><input class="col-md-12 same_class_name" id="div_id2" type="text" placeholder="age"  style="display:none;" required></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><input class="col-md-12 same_class_name" id="div_id3" type="text" placeholder="height"  style="display:none;" required></div>
</div>
```

drop down option
    submit button
      div1
      div2
      div3

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: @ j08691 yes, I am

Comment: Have you tried actually hiding the div and not the input within the div? In your example you applied the display none to the input but not the wrapping div.

Comment: If you can use pure js under your code it is done. if you want I can provide you the js code?

Comment: @AlirezaNazari sure i'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

The most easy way in pure JS, you just need to add this code `onchange="myFunction()"` to your select element and the rest will handled by JS function.

```html
<select id="selection_id" name="selection_id" class="form-control" onchange="myFunction()">
            <option>Please Make A Selection</option>
            <option value="name">Name</option>
            <option value="age">Age</option>
            <option value="height">Height</option>
        </select>

<div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-3" id="div1">
          <input class="col-md-12 same_class_name" id="div_id1" 
            type="text" placeholder="name"  style="display:none;" required>
          </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" id="div2">
          <input class="col-md-12 same_class_name" id="div_id2" 
            type="text" placeholder="age"  style="display:none;" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" id="div3">
          <input class="col-md-12 same_class_name" id="div_id3" 
            type="text" placeholder="height"  style="display:none;" required>
        </div>
  </div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("selection_id").value;
  
  switch(x) {
  case "name":
    document.getElementById("div_id1").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("div_id2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("div_id3").style.display = "none";
    break;
  case "age":
    document.getElementById("div_id1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("div_id2").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("div_id3").style.display = "none";
    break;
  case "height":
    document.getElementById("div_id1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("div_id2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("div_id3").style.display = "inline";
    break;
  default:
    document.getElementById("div_id1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("div_id2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("div_id3").style.display = "none";

 }
}
</script>
```

**[Updated]**
If you can include jQuery in your web page then the following code give you, same result, I think you probably do the same.

```js
$('#selection_id').on('change', function(){
    var selection = $(this).val();
    $('[id^=div_id]').hide();
    switch(selection) {
      case "name":   $('#div_id1').show(); break;
      case "age":    $('#div_id2').show(); break;
      case "height": $('#div_id3').show(); break;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selection_id" name="selection_id" class="form-control">
    <option>Please Make A Selection</option>
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="age">Age</option>
    <option value="height">Height</option>
</select>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3" id="div1"><input class="col-md-12 same_class_name" id="div_id1" type="text" placeholder="name" style="display:none;" required></div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="div2"><input class="col-md-12 same_class_name" id="div_id2" type="text" placeholder="age"  style="display:none;" required></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><input class="col-md-12 same_class_name" id="div_id3" type="text" placeholder="height"  style="display:none;" required></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you @alireza, in my existing code I was using switch cases as you suggested, but did apply styling as you've done. I was using jquery .show()/.hide(). This works for what I need. I've upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of this approach:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#selection_id').on('change', function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        hideAllInputs();
        if(value === 'name'){
          $('#div_id1').show();
        }else if(value === 'age'){
          $('#div_id2').show();
        }else if(value === 'height'){
          $('#div_id3').show();
        }
        
    });
});

function hideAllInputs(){
  $('#div_id1').hide();
  $('#div_id2').hide();
  $('#div_id3').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selection_id" name="selection_id" class="form-control">
            <option>Please Make A Selection</option>
            <option value="name">Name</option>
            <option value="age">Age</option>
            <option value="height">Height</option>
        </select>

  <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-3"><input class="col-md-12 same_class_name" id="div_id1" type="text" placeholder="name"  style="display:none;" required></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><input class="col-md-12 same_class_name" id="div_id2" type="text" placeholder="age"  style="display:none;" required></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><input class="col-md-12 same_class_name" id="div_id3" type="text" placeholder="height"  style="display:none;" required></div>
  </div>
```